# Why is the num pad considered character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is working fine, but if I use my num pad (right side), it will consider it a character and delete it but the numbers in the left side is accepted. I want my num pad (right side) to be accepted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("input[name='inputDate']:first").keyup(function(e){
        var key=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if(!( key >= 0 && key <= 9 )) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,$(this).val().length-1));
        }
    });

</script>
```

---

Updated with this (already solved)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $("input[name='birthdate']:first").on('keyup', function(e){
            var val = $(this).val();
            var key = val.substr(val.length - 1)
            var value=$(this).val();
            if(value.length === 2|| value.length === 5)$(this).val($(this).val()+'/');
            if(!(key>=0&&key<=9))
              $(this).val(val.substr(0,val.length-1));
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: Why check the keycode when you could just check the input value?

Comment: my code dont accept the numbers input in the num pad, only in the 1-9 of keyboard (left side).

Comment: Unclear?! What exactly is unclear? The code is pretty much self-explanatory: OP wants an input where only digits can be entered. Moreover, if it's a date input, then there are better solution he is not probably not aware of. Instead of saying "IT'S UNCLEAR" better to show the alternatives, IMHO anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, reading the last character instead of key code:

```
$("input[name='inputDate']:first").on('keyup', function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var key = val.substr(val.length - 1)
    if(!(key>=0&&key<=9))
      $(this).val(val.substr(0,val.length-1));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cek125i/R55G8/)

Note - this won't "protect" you from text being pasted in the input field! For that you'll need to bind `input` event. Also, a very fast typing can result in some letter "getting trough". So...

#### A better way of doing the same:

```
$('input[name="inputDate"]:first').on('input', function(e){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '') );
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cek125i/MLj6F/)

#### And finally...

If you are creating a date input field and want to make it so that regular visitors can only input a valid date, check out [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), or maybe some other "input mask" solution.

Be aware that this can still be bypassed with a number of ways and a server-side check is almost always necessary.

Comment: I thought ur code will work but it's not working... maybe i'll try the input mask

Comment: @Ghost fixed an error and made JSFiddles for both examples.

Comment: oh sorry, it's working, but the format is gone... I mean is there a way to auto input a "/" after 2 number? the format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: for that it's best to use an "input mask", see the link I provided. There is, of course, a way of doing it "manually" but I'd recommend agains it - don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I also tried the input mask but it's not working for me, maybe i'll stick for the edited part I post above. but thankz, i really appreciate ur help